# How to Bold and Color specific text in String

Tags: android

I am developing an app where I use material design dialog to show some information to user ,what I want is to make a part of text style bold in dialog.How can I acheive this problem.

here is Image of my dialog :-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVdqJ.png)

here I want this mobile number text style bold and color

here is my code :-

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CRegistrationScreen.this);
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setMessage("We will send you a verification SMS to this Number.\n\n"+s_szResponseMobileNum+"\n\nIs this OK,or would you like to edit the number.");
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null);
            builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.edit,null);
            builder.show();
```

Comment: make custom dialog for this.it is easy to custom your text style and color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **specific style text** we want to convert text into **HTML** and use **HTML TAG** for styling

try this may be it work....................

```
 String sourceString = "We will send you a verification SMS to this Number.<br><br> <b><font color='#08b608'>" + s_szResponseMobileNum + "</b> <br><br>Is this OK,or would you like to edit the number." ; 
builder.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(sourceString));
```

with output:-[image]

enjoy coding.....................

Comment: I thik you dont understand my question

Comment: I want mobile mentioned above style and color only

Comment: only mobile number

Comment: but I want  to start mobile between two text and have gap

Comment: ?? not getting you question

Comment: I want to start mobile number from new line

Comment: it is <br> <br> tag which is used same as \n in HTML

Comment: ok... if I want to change color of that mobile number Is this possible

Answer (score 0):

You could basically use html tags in your string resource like:

```
<resource>
  <string id="@+id/no">We will send you a verification SMS to this Number <b>your mobile no</b>this OK,or would you like to edit the number</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: but mobile number is that which is I am getting from server response and saved in varibale named as "s_szResponseMobileNum" then how I define in string xml

Comment: @Nitin make custom dialog so u can change any text style or color

Comment: @Nitin try this ref: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/  otherwise send your mail id i am sending your demo

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you a step by step guide

**STEP 1**

Add support lib in your gradle file

```
dependencies {  
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:X.X.X' // where X.X.X version
}
```

**STEP 2**

Make your activity extend `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.`

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {  
        ...
    }
```

**STEP 3**  Create alert dialog

```
private void showLocationDialog() {  
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.dialog_title));   
 builder.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(""+"<b>"+R.string.dialog_message+"</b>"));

String positiveText = getString(android.R.string.ok);
    builder.setPositiveButton(positiveText,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // positive button logic
        }
    });

    String negativeText = getString(android.R.string.cancel);
    builder.setNegativeButton(negativeText,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // negative button logic
        }
    });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    // display dialog
    dialog.show();
}
```

**STEP 4**

Declare custom **drawable.xml** for dialog background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<!-- From: support/v7/appcompat/res/drawable/abc_dialog_material_background_light.xml -->  
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:insetLeft="16dp"
    android:insetTop="16dp"
    android:insetRight="16dp"
    android:insetBottom="16dp">

    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/indigo" />
    </shape>

</inset>
```

Declare style in **style.xml** file

```
<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">  
    <!--buttons color-->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/pink</item>
    <!--title and message color-->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <!--dialog background-->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_dialog</item>
</style>
```

**STEP 5** **Final step**

Create your dialog and use style as parameter in AlertDialog.Builder.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder =  
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.MyDialogTheme);
...
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();  
// display dialog
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your query by below code which will help you to show number in bold with particular color.

You can use Spannable class for this, try below code.

```
        String strMessage = “We will send you a verification SMS to this Number.\n\n” + s_szResponseMobileNum + "\n\nIs this OK,or would you like to edit the number."

        Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString(strMessage);        

        wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), strMessage.indexOf(s_szResponseMobileNum), s_szResponseMobileNum.length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        wordtoSpan.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), strMessage.indexOf(s_szResponseMobileNum), s_szResponseMobileNum.length, 0);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CRegistrationScreen.this);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setMessage(wordtoSpan);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null);
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.edit,null);
        builder.show();
```

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`StyleSpan`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/StyleSpan.html) to make specific parts of the text bold.

```
SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder();
ssb.append("We will send you a verification SMS to this Number:\n\n");
int start = ssb.length();
ssb.append(phoneNumber);
ssb.append("\n\nIs this OK, or would you like to edit the number?");
ssb.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), start, phoneNumber.length(), 
        Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CRegistrationScreen.this);
builder.setCancelable(false)
        .setMessage(ssb)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null)
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.edit, null)
        .show();
```